# Find the general solution of $y'''+y'=0$ for $y(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently working on this example problem from our lecture notes.

In the solution, it says:

"The given equation does not depend on $y$. Hence we use the order-reducing substitution $y′=w$, which gives

$w''+w=0$

This new equation does not depend on $x$. A useful order-reducing substitution now is more sophisticated: $\frac{dw}{dx}=z(w)$. By the chain rule:

$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dw}{dx}) = \frac{d}{dx} (z(w)) = \frac{dz}{dw} \frac{dw}{dx} = z \frac{dz}{dw}$
"

(From here, I think I'm comfortable solving the equation)

Though I understand the substitution and use of the chain rule, I don't really understand what it's saying.

The line "The new equation does not depend on $x$" seriously confuses me. Isn't $x$ the independent variable, and so must depend on it? In a similar way, I'm a bit confused with the sentence "The given equation does not depend on $Y$", but I think that's just saying "Because y isn't the independent variable, you're allowed to substitute", right?

I don't understand what $z(w)$ represents either. I'm assuming it's just the function of $w$ that represents what happens to $w$ after being differentiated with respect to $x$, but I'm not sure.

Any feedback would be much appreciated!

Comment: About the line "the new equation does not depend on $x$", I believe it is a clumsy way of stating that the coefficients in the differential equation $w'' + w = 0$ are constant (ie. do not depend on $x$). The notation $z(w)$ however is also confusing to me, as well as the application of the chain rule. Are the lecture notes from physics or chemistry?

Comment: Your equation $w'' + w = 0 $ can be solved directly, just use sine and cosine. Then integrate to get y.

Comment: @Suzet But if $w=y'$ and $y$ depends on $x$, doesn't $w$ implicity depend on $x$? Even if it is differentiated? 

Glad I'm not the only one struggling to understand it. It's actually a maths module about ODEs.

Comment: @Suzet A trick when you want to reduce the order of an "autonomous" ODE (not depending on the independent variable $x$ explicitly) is to exchange the dependent and independent variable and write the equation for $x(y)$. Now, since there is no dependence in $x$ in the original equation, the new equation now depends on the derivatives of $x(y)$ but not on $x(y)$. You then reduce the order by defining $z(y):=x'(y)$. In that text, they do the two steps in one substitutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The given equation does not depend on $y$" means that it depends on the derivatives of $y$ but not $y$ itself. For example, the equation $y''+y'+2y=0$ would "depend on $y$". So, in that last equation, the substitution $w=y'$ would not work.

"The new equation does not depend on $x$", really should be written as "The new equation does not explicitly depend on $x$". An example where this would not be the case is: $y''+e^xy'+2xy=0$. The proposed substitution would not work in that case.

I do agree with you the wording might be a little confusing if you are not used to it.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am glad it worked out. Could you "approve" the answer by clicking on the check mark?